# Error when running the apk on Device (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse

I don´t know why the app is running only in process debug by device. When i try to use the app on the device the app doesn´t work. I show the error below.

```
12-25 11:58:51.829: E/Trace(30281): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.menu/com.example.menu.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3278)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3332)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3530)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.app.ContextImpl.stopService(ContextImpl.java:1319)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService(ContextWrapper.java:395)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at com.example.menu.MainActivity.onStop(MainActivity.java:125)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1208)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5322)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3273)
12-25 11:58:52.354: E/AndroidRuntime(30281):    ... 12 more
```

The code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, Runnable, OnSeekBarChangeListener  {

    private Intent svc;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private SeekBar sb; 
    private AudioManager am;

    int Volume=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.spalshduck);
        mp.start(); 

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);




    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        ImageButton soundButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound);
        soundButton.setOnTouchListener(this);   

    }
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sound:
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.soundview);
            ImageButton soundButtonback = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.soundback);

            sb  =(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

            am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            mp.start();

            int maxVolume = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            int curVolume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            sb.setMax(maxVolume);
            sb.setProgress(curVolume);

            sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

            soundButtonback.setOnTouchListener(this);


            break;
        }

        case R.id.soundback:
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ImageButton soundButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound);
            soundButton.setOnTouchListener(this);   
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;

    }


    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekb, int progress, boolean arg2) {
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
        Volume = progress;      
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volume: " + Integer.toString(Volume), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        return true;
    }

    public void finish() {
        stopService(svc);
        super.finish();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        stopService(svc);
        super.onStop();



    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    svc=new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    startService(svc);


    addListenerOnButton();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }   

}
```

No ideia to solve this problem :-(

Comment: check  `if(svc !=null)` before stopping service

Answer (score 0):

The problems happens when the activity is stopped because the `svc` field is still `null`. The code you have in the `run` method should probably go into the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Not entirely.  You can go through many onStart()/onStop() cycles, without hitting another onCreate(), so the handling of the service starting and stopping needs to be somewhat symmetric with respect to the activity lifecycle's potential looping, though you might be able to create the Intent object earlier and keep it around.